# Table formatting problem in two columns: lines won't extend to the end. "Overfull \hbox" error

Tags: tables

I've got a two-column article and I'm trying to make a long table which cannot fit into a single column.  The only trouble I'm having in overriding the formatting seems to be that the lines containing the table won't extend to the end.

When I run LaTeX, I'm told:

> Overfull \hbox (127.68214pt too wide) in alignment at lines 44--51
>
> [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []

Here's what the code looks like:

```
\documentclass[twocol]{ametsoc}

...

\begin{table}
\caption{Arctic radiative fluxes under standard conditions.}
\begin{tabular*}{\hsize}{@{\extracolsep\fill}|l|ccccccccc|@{}}
\topline
Height& SW$_{up}$& SW$_{down}$& SW$_{net}$& LW$_{up}$& LW$_{down}$& LW$_{net}$& Net Up& Net Down& Net Flux\\
\midline
\ TOA& 57.7& 144.1& -86.4& 171.0& \phantom{1}\phantom{1}0.0& 171.0& 228.7& 144.1& 84.6\\
\ SFC& 21.1& \phantom{1}81.6& -60.6& 194.2& 134.6& \phantom{1}59.7& 215.3& 216.2& -0.9\\
\botline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE!. Please expend your code sniped to complete document, which has all to table related package! Help us to help you.

Comment: You should use `table*` and not `table`; also `\hsize` should be `\textwidth`.

Comment: Your table is to wide for fit in one column only. Consider @egreg comment.

Answer (score 3):

Since the tabular material is wider than a single column, you need to use a combination of `table*` and `tabular` environments, not a combination of `table` and `tabular*`. Do also use a column type, such as `S` (provided by the `siunitx` package), that facilitates typesetting negative numbers and aligning numbers on their decimal markers. And do use `\textsubscript` rather than math mode to typeset text in subscript positions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocol]{ametsoc}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for "S" column type
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Arctic radiative fluxes under standard conditions.}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{9}{S[table-format=3.1]}|@{}}
\topline
Height& {SW\textsubscript{up}} & {SW\textsubscript{down}} & {SW\textsubscript{net}} 
      & {LW\textsubscript{up}} & {LW\textsubscript{down}} & {LW\textsubscript{net}} 
      & {Net Up} & {Net Down} & {Net Flux} \\
\midline
TOA& 57.7& 144.1& -86.4& 171.0& 0.0& 171.0& 228.7& 144.1& 84.6\\
SFC& 21.1& 81.6& -60.6& 194.2& 134.6& 59.7& 215.3& 216.2& -0.9\\
\botline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: In case it's important to typeset the tabular material so that it spans the full width of both columns, you could use either a `tabular*` or a `tabularx` environment, with the width set to `\textwidth`. (`\hsize` is a low-level TeX macro which should, with a few exceptions, not be invoked directly.) The following screenshot contrasts the looks of the `tabular`, `tabular*`, and `tabularx`-based solutions. Observe that the setup of the third, `tabularx`-based solution is a bit of a hybrid: the main column type for the nine data columns is `S`, but the nine header cells are typeset using a centered version of the `X` column type.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocol]{ametsoc}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for "S" column type
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering

\caption{Using a \texttt{tabular} environment}
\begin{tabular}{|c| S[table-format=2.1] *{8}{S[table-format=3.1]}|@{}}
\topline
Height& {SW\textsubscript{up}} & {SW\textsubscript{down}} & {SW\textsubscript{net}} 
      & {LW\textsubscript{up}} & {LW\textsubscript{down}} & {LW\textsubscript{net}} 
      & {Net Up} & {Net Down} & {Net Flux} \\
\midline
TOA& 57.7& 144.1& -86.4& 171.0& 0.0& 171.0& 228.7& 144.1& 84.6\\
SFC& 21.1& 81.6& -60.6& 194.2& 134.6& 59.7& 215.3& 216.2& -0.9\\
\botline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\caption{Using a \texttt{tabular*} environment}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c| 
           S[table-format=2.1] *{8}{S[table-format=3.1]}|@{}}
\topline
Height& {SW\textsubscript{up}} & {SW\textsubscript{down}} & {SW\textsubscript{net}} 
      & {LW\textsubscript{up}} & {LW\textsubscript{down}} & {LW\textsubscript{net}} 
      & {Net Up} & {Net Down} & {Net Flux} \\
\midline
TOA& 57.7& 144.1& -86.4& 171.0& 0.0& 171.0& 228.7& 144.1& 84.6\\
SFC& 21.1& 81.6& -60.6& 194.2& 134.6& 59.7& 215.3& 216.2& -0.9\\
\botline
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\caption{Using a \texttt{tabularx} environment}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C| 
           S[table-format=2.1] *{8}{S[table-format=3.1]}|@{}}
\topline
Height& \mc{SW\textsubscript{up}} & \mc{SW\textsubscript{down}} & \mc{SW\textsubscript{net}} 
      & \mc{LW\textsubscript{up}} & \mc{LW\textsubscript{down}} & \mc{LW\textsubscript{net}} 
      & \mc{Net Up} & \mc{Net Down} & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{Net Flux} \\
\midline
TOA& 57.7& 144.1& -86.4& 171.0& 0.0& 171.0& 228.7& 144.1& 84.6\\
SFC& 21.1& 81.6& -60.6& 194.2& 134.6& 59.7& 215.3& 216.2& -0.9\\
\botline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you beat me (again) for few seconds :(. good solution!